# searching within an array of structs in c

Tags: c, arrays, search, struct

i see plenty of examples on how to search arrays to find a specific instance what i want to do is find all the instances and print them for example i have this struct

```
struct BookInfo
{
    char title[50];
    int numAuthors;
    char authors[50][50];
    int year;
    int checkedout;
};

struct BookInfo library[500];
```

and i have a function to search within the years but it only gives me the first instance it finds how do i get it to give me bot instances???
heres the function

```
int yearsearch()
{
int target, i, l, r, mid;
    l = 0;
    r = 14-1;
    printf("type a year to search for book");
    scanf("%d", &target);

    while(l <= r)
    {
        mid = (l+r)/2;
        if(library[mid].year == target)
        {
            printf("\n%s",library[mid].title);
            printf("  %d",library[mid].year);
            printf("These are all the books with that year");
            break;
        }
        else if (library[mid].year < target)
        {
            l = mid + 1;
        }
        else
        {
            r = mid - 1;

        }

        if(l > r)
            printf("The target is not in the array.\n");

    }
menu();

}
```

Comment: (in response to a deleted comment suggesting removing the 'break') Removing the break would cause this to loop forever without terminating in some instances.  This is *not* the correct solution as it is as it may miss certain elements if 'mid' happens to land in the middle of the entries for a given year.

Comment: when i did that the programs never stops printing the first instance it finds lol

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You're doing a kind of binary search over the array, which is not designed to find all instances without modification.  Have you considered just doing a linear search (i.e., a `for` loop) over the length of the array and printing if the array element matches your search criteria?  One might implement a naive linear search like this:

```
for (int i = 0; i<500; i++) {
   if (library[i].year == target) {
       // Do your printing here
   }

   // Otherwise do nothing!
}
```

Comment: did not know that about the binary search how does one implement a linear search (looking it up myself)

Comment: A binary search is only useful for determining if a particular entry exists in a sorted list.

Comment: That's not *strictly* true.  A binary search with added linear probing can be used to determine all occurrences in a sorted list, too.  You binary search until you find a matching element, then you seek back to find the start of the matching range, and then seek forward to find the end of the matching range.  I just suggested going for a linear search because of the small number of elements involved and because it's much simpler.

Comment: since i have your help at the moment what if i was searching one of the char arrays instead can i use the same code by just switching target to a char instead of an int

Comment: No, the index will remain an 'int', but the general technique will be the same.  In C the indexes to an array are always of type 'int'.  If you want to post some code you can post a new question and I will help you there.

Comment: @xaxxon: Not exactly. In author's code,`mid` variable has same value as `i` value in this line-search by Gian,if found element.